# How come recursive functions return something?

Tags: c, function, recursion, logic, recursive-query

I saw a recursive function example in c language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int n);
int main(){
    int num,add;
    printf("Enter a positive integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    add=sum(num);
    printf("sum=%d",add);
}
int sum(int n){
    if(n==0)
       return n;
    else
       return n+sum(n-1);    /*self call  to function sum() */
}
```

but here i cannot understand sum function actually returns only 0 which is visible from the code else it will return itself plus `n` .

So how come function call is translated into number theres no line in the function that tells to return also n itself except that it's 0 .

Comment: Very good question +1 for the inception. I to am wondering the answer.

Comment: Just follow the logic.  If `n` is 0, then it of course returns 0.  What if `n` is 1?  Then it returns `1 + sum(0)`.  Well, `sum(0)` is 0.  So `1 + sum(0)` is 1.  Get it?  Following the same logic, `sum(2)` is 3, `sum(3)` is 6, etc.

Comment: Look up "base case" that will help you out, when it returns 0 that is the base case to the recursion

Comment: the problem here is this function is only allowed to return 0 how it returns something else

Comment: A better question might be: why write such a needlessly slow and painfully inefficient function for something so simple? It is very bad programming. Please don't study how to do very bad programming.

Comment: @Lundin what are you talking about? understanding how recursion works is very important for learning programming.

Comment: @RoadRunner It is not, it is very peripheral feature that has very limited use. There are a few cases where you would want to use recursion to optimize overall memory use, certain binary trees etc. But in most cases recursion is just incredibly slow, ugly, and dangerous.

Comment: Yeah that's true I guess. But having a good knowledge of it is still beneficial, just to see what traps you can run into. I certainly don't regret not learning it, as I can understand what it does and what things can go wrong, but 99% of the time I would never use it.

Comment: I apologise for the rudeness @Lundin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you observe the sum() function - it has a return type of int.
Which means when we return from this function - the return value will be an integer.

Now this statement here is the key to any recursive routine:

```
return n + sum(n-1);
```

Here, we are calling sum() again for (n-1) and it is supposed to return an integer. And before returning from this function - we will just add 'n' to it and return an integer from here.

This recursive routine can be thought of as :

```
sum(3) = 3 + sum(2) = 3 + 2 + sum(1) = 3 + 2 + 1 + sum(0)
```

Which is finally equal to : 3+2+1+0

Comment: still makes no sense this function is returning a number plus a function which has return type of num but itself is a function

Comment: now i start to understand but isnt this an awfull way to do loops there will be thousands of function calls for big numbers which **will always just return 1** who wants to do that instead of this a basic loop can handle this much efficient @pankaj is there any reason that a person might want to use this instead of a loop?

Comment: @nikoss In this example, you are correct, it's a terrible way to implement this particular functionality.  In that sense, it is a poor candidate for a recursive solution.  There are, however, other problems for which recursion is natural and efficient.

Comment: Please do read about recursive routines and some sample usage. As @nikoss, has mentioned this is a terrible way for this particular use case, but consider reading about Tower of Hanoi problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi

Comment: Also, to understand the concept of recursion, please read about function call stack -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Answer (score 4):

In the below function,

```
int sum(int n){
    if(n==0)
       return n;
    else
       return n+sum(n-1);    /* sum() returns int so its n+(returned int) */
}
```

it return an `int`.

The `else` part calls a function which in-turn returns an `int` and then it does the add & return the final value.

```
sum(1) => 1+sum(0) => 1+0 => 1
sum(2) => 2+sum(1) => 2+(1+sum(0)) => 2+(1+0) => 2+(1) => 3
...
```

You may also write it as -

`sum(3) => 3+sum(2) => 6`

OR

```
sum(3) => 3+sum(2+sum(1+sum(0))) => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to all those good explanations, i prepared a recursive tree to help you to understand recursive schematically. If we take `sum(3)` as start

```
         sum(3)
      _____|_____
      |         |
      1    +  sum(2)
             ___|___
             |     |
             1  + sum(1)
                ___|___
                |     |
                1  +  0 => base part (if condition came true)
```

And note that all the schema will keep waiting until function get the base part. In a manner, hierarchy gets more specific from top to bottom until it finds out the answer; then it will begin to close all the twigs from bottom to top.

Comment: it makes sense but who wants to use this way instead of a loop a big number means thousands of function calls just to return 1 always @taha isnt this stupidity ?

Comment: Of course it is, for this example. This tree is just to explain '**recursive logic**'. But in some problems, using recursive is really necessary for efficiency and complexity like this: http://www.cquestions.com/2008/01/c-program-for-binary-search-through.html.